# Is there a way to secure a powerpoint presentation against edits?

Tags: security, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have a few powerpoint slideshows I need to distribute, but I would like the receivers to not be able to edit them.  They still need to be able to launch embedded links though.

It seems like this is a difficult task, given the nature of powerpoint and I've read quite a few conflicting reports on different aspects.  Some say that password protecting from editing allows the end user to save a copy without restrictions, much like word or excel, others suggest it won't allow that.

I've read about some 3rd party software solutions like [SecurePack](http://skp.mvps.org/securepack/), which doesn't seem like an optimal choice after reading their FAQ. Alternately, is the Microsoft [Information Rights Management](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/free-trial-service-for-information-rights-management-HA001072168.aspx) service, but that doesn't really seem like it would let me accomplish what I am looking to do anyhow.

Does anyone know of a way to allow the files to be playable, yet keep their content relatively secure?

Comment: "*Relatively* secure" is important here. If they're determined, you don't stand a chance. You need to be aware of that.

Comment: I'm just hoping to find something that is slightly better than trivial and also not $100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not save the presentation as a PDF? Some formatting may not work out perfectly, but links will still work and it will not be editable as a PowerPoint file.

Comment: I figured exporting to PDF would break the links by just converting the whole slide to an image, I didn't know PowerPoint could export to PDF natively.

Comment: Ended up going with this option as it would be the easiest to deal with for the intended target.  The File|Save As|PDF or XPS option really produces some nice looking files, I was very impressed.

Comment: I also used Nuance PDF Convertor 7 to apply some other document security options, such as disabling copy/paste and printing from the PDF. This kept the links clickable as well. I wasn't able to strip the security from the document when I saved it using v1.7 encryption.

Answer (score 7):

Three options I can think of:

1. Under the Office menu|Prepare, you can select Mark as Final, which restricts editing. Note that this is not security based as any user can turn it off, but it's a reasonable indicator. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/prevent-changes-to-a-final-version-of-a-document-HA010132569.aspx.
2. You could set a Modify password under Tools|General Options on the Save As... dialogue.  [image]
3. You could save as another format such as PDF or XPS as RichardM suggests.

Comment: I'd never even noticed that dropdown box on the save-as menu.

Comment: After trying the modify password and the Save As|PDF option I decided to go with the Save As PDF. I accepted RichardM's answer since he posted the one I used first, but I'd totally upvote you if I had enough rep though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To export your PowerPoint presentation, you have several options including video format (ideal for presentations with audio narrations or animations), PDF file, or a folder of images with each image representing a slide. For online viewing, popular platforms include Slideshare and Docs.com. If you have exported your presentation as a video, consider uploading it to YouTube or Facebook for maximum accessibility.

Comment: Instead of converting to a folder of images, it is better to convert in to a PowerPoint slide show of images. This can be done in two clicks with this little script: http://j.mp/pptraster (disclaimer: I wrote it).

Comment: That's a great option, too! It preserves Notes and Slide Transitions. And you can still use PowerPoint to present the slides in Presenter Mode.